# as3 finding the offset of a block

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to make a pong like game but i need to find the offset from the center of the paddle so that i can make it bounce differently depending on where it hits the paddle. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
   // get the center of the paddle
    var centerXpaddle = paddle.x - paddle.width/2;
    var centerYpaddle =  paddle.y -paddle.height/2;

if (objectThatHits.hitTestObject(paddle)) {
    // get the current point of object
   var offsetX = objectThatHits.x - centerXpaddle;
   var offsetY = objectThatHits.y - centerYpaddle;
}
```

The first two lines get the center of the the paddle (it's current position minus half the width and half the height) and the second part is a "test" for when the "object that hits"  hits the "paddle".

Comment: How does this reflect the point where the ball hit the paddle?

Comment: im not sure but i dont think your alowed to name a var like that in as3, did you mean some thing like var centerXpaddle:Number = paddle.x - paddle.width/2

Comment: i tried what you said and it always comes up with the same number which is offsetX = 31.5
offsetY = 163

Comment: Ok never mind i figured out something of a solution that sometimes gives slightly radical numbers but i can apply something to regulate it